# Does Eclipse automatically set "uses-permissions" in Manifest?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest

I know it's a simple question but I can't find any answer. Well actually it's three related questions:

1. If my code requires a `uses-permission` manifest element, does Eclipse automatically add it to the manifest?
2. If Eclipse doesn't automatically add it, how do I know which permissions my app needs? Of course there is [this list](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html), but it's hard to go though this list checking if what my app does falls within each of these permissions.
3. If Eclipse doesn't automatically add the permission and I fail to do it, how will I find out? Will the app fail to install on the emulator? Will it install on the emulator but be force-closed when trying to access something it doesn't have permissions for? Or do I have to install the apk on a real device in order to find out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If my code requires a uses-permission manifest element, does Eclipse automatically add it to the manifest?

No.

> how do I know which permissions my app needs?

Generally, by reading the JavaDocs, which do a decent job of pointing out what permissions you need. Otherwise, you will find out in testing, when your app crashes with a `SecurityException`.

> If Eclipse doesn't automatically add the permission and I fail to do it, how will I find out?

See above.

> Will it install on the emulator but be force-closed when trying to access something it doesn't have permissions for?

Correct.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse will not add permissions automatically. However, if you try to use a feature that requires permission, you *will* be made aware of the missing permission. Here's an excerpt from android resource page on `Permissions`: [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html)

> Often times a permission failure will result in a SecurityException
>   being thrown back to the application. However, this is not guaranteed
>   to occur everywhere. For example, the sendBroadcast(Intent) method
>   checks permissions as data is being delivered to each receiver, after
>   the method call has returned, so you will not receive an exception if
>   there are permission failures. In almost all cases, however, a
>   permission failure will be printed to the system log.

Your third question is answered by:

> In almost all cases, however, a permission failure will be printed to
>   the system log.

Just in case you're wondering about what you would see in Logcat:

> 11-20 08:08:47.766: E/AndroidRuntime(9380):
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH permission: Neither user
>   10111 nor current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse does not automatically add the `uses-permission` to your manifest. I once had forgot to add a permission and had my app fail when it got to that part of the code. I can't remember the exact error but it did mention that a permission was required to use the method I tried using and I believe that it told me what permission.

If you don't add one in then you will soon find out.